# Chern character of a sheaf with support of given dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, characteristic-classes

Let $\mathscr{F}^\bullet$ be a complex of coherent sheaves on a smooth projective variety $X$.
Suppose that the support of $\mathscr{F}^\bullet$ (the union of the supports of the cohomology sheaves, if I understand correctly) has dimension $k$.
Why does it follow that the Chern character $\mathrm{ch}(\mathscr{F}^\bullet)$ is zero in codimensions 0 to $k - 1$?
(The Chern character of a complex is defined to be the Chern character of its Euler characteristic.)

Edit: this is supposed to be true for a complex $\mathscr{F}^\bullet$ on the product $X \times Y$ of two n-dimensional varieties which is supported in dimension n.  Maybe the above generalization is incorrect.

Comment: Let $\mathscr{F}^\bullet$ be a locally free sheaf, and $k=\operatorname{dim}X$, in this simplest situation Chern character is not zero in dimensions $0$ to $k-1$.

Comment: @Alex: please see the edit.  Also could you give an example of such a sheaf?

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be codimension $k$?  That seems to make more sense.

Comment: @Rhys: sorry, I meant the chern character should be zero in _co_dimension less than k (I think).

Comment: I think it's clearer to say if the support of $\mathcal{F}$ has codimension $k$, then $c_i = 0$ for $i=0,\ldots,k-1$. (I'm not saying that this is definitely true - although I think it is - but either way, it seems to be the statement you are trying to make.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\newcommand{\F}{\mathscr{F}}\F$ be a coherent sheaf on a smooth variety $X$.
Let $Z = \mathrm{Supp}(\F) \subset X$ be the support of $\F$, considered as a closed subscheme with the [``annihilator'' scheme structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34621/what-in-the-meaning-of-schematic-support).
Then one has the sheaf $i^*(\F)$ on $Z$, which is still coherent with support $Z$, and further there is a canonical isomorphism $\F \stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow} i_*(i^*(\F))$.
Now by the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem the cycle $\newcommand{\ch}{\mathrm{ch}}\ch(\F) = \ch(i_*(i^*(\F)))$ lies in the image of the homomorphism $i_* : A_*(Z) \to A_*(X)$.
The latter maps cycles of codimension $j$ to cycles of codimension $n-m+j$, where $m = \dim(Z)$ and $n = \dim(X)$.
In particular the Chern character $\ch(\F)$ has no components in codimension less than $n - m$.